# AngularJs ng-show usage

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-show

I am new on AngularJs and I want to see header when only checkbox value is true. I set its initial value false but header is showing in first running. My question is why header is showing in first time without any click?

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.myVar = "false";
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <form>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myVar">if u want to see header click this checkbox</input>
    <h1 ng-show="myVar">show this if checkbox returned true</h1>
    </br>
    {{myVar}}
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: $scope.myVar = false should work

Answer (score 0):

you are assigning a string to myVar, thus coercing it to boolean, it always comes `true`. Assign it to a real boolean: `$scope.myVar = false`

Answer (score 0):

Because of you assigned value is a string . Just give only boolean value that's working fine.

```html
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>  
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
        <form>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myVar">if u want to see header click this checkbox</input>
            <h1 ng-show="myVar">show this if checkbox returned true</h1></br>
            {{myVar}}
        </form>
    </div>
<script>
    var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);
    app.controller("myController",function($scope){
        $scope.myVar=false;
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove quotation marks from $scope.myVar = "false"; 
Here you are assigning a string value to $scope.myVar and hence when you load on your page for the first time it doesn't work as it does not get the desired boolean value.